# WordPress jQuery driven static sidebar

Tags: jquery, wordpress, static, sidebar

I am using the following tweaked jQuery code to float my WordPress page sidebar.

```
    function loadStaticSidebar(){

    //floating sidebar menu
    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 15;
    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

}
```

It archives what I want it to... stick to the same position when I scroll down the page and so forth.

**Issue:** 
I want it to stop scrolling when it gets to the bottom of the page. At the moment and never stop scolling and it breaks the website. Someone told me I need to measure the windows size on load - no sure how to go about implementing that.... Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){ // document ready

  if (!!$('#sidebar').offset()) { // make sure "#sidebar" element exists

    var stickyTop = $('#sidebar').offset().top; // returns number

    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event

      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

      if (stickyTop < windowTop){
        $('#sidebar').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0 });
      }
      else {
        $('#sidebar').css('position','static');
      }

    });

  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you Sridhar for the reply. It works but like my script... if you keep scrolling down it does not break. Here is an image of what happens: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmmvqlpawvo0s7w/issue.PNG

Comment: what problem you face